# Subdifferentials of a strictly convex function are disjoint

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, normed-spaces, convex-analysis, subgradient

I'm trying to prove below result which is mentioned in page 24 of Santambrogio's *Optimal Transport for Applied Mathematicians: Calculus of Variations, PDEs, and Modeling*. Could you have a check on my attempt?

> **Theorem:** Let $E$ be a normed space and $f:E \to \mathbb R$ strictly convex. Then $\partial f (a) \cap \partial f (b) = \emptyset$ for all $a\neq b$.

---

**Proof:** We need the following useful result whose proof is given at the end.

*Lemma:* If $\varphi \in \partial f (a)$ then $f(x) - f(a) > \langle \varphi, x-a \rangle$ for all $x\neq a$.

Assume the contrary that there are $a \neq b$ such that there is $\varphi \in \partial f (a) \cap \partial f (b)$. Then by our *Lemma*,
$$
f(b) - f(a) > \langle \varphi, b-a \rangle \quad \text{and} \quad f(a) - f(b) > \langle \varphi, a-b \rangle.
$$

It follows that
$$
f(b)-f(a) > \langle \varphi, b-a \rangle> f(b)-f(a),
$$

which is a contradiction. This completes the proof.

---

*Proof of the lemma:* Assume the contrary that there is $b \neq a$ such that $f(b) - f(a) = \langle \varphi, b-a \rangle$. Let $c := (a+b)/2$. Then
$$
\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2} > f(c) \ge f(a) + \langle \varphi, c-a \rangle.
$$

It follows that
$$
\frac{2f(a) + \langle \varphi, b-a \rangle}{2} > f(a) + \langle \varphi, c-a \rangle.
$$

So $\langle \varphi, b-a \rangle > \langle \varphi, 2(c-a) \rangle$. On the other hand, $2(c-a) = b-a$. Then we obtain a contradiction.

Comment: All is good to me. Just be a little careful with your hypothesis. The space $E$ should me more than a normed space if you want to take inner products.

Comment: @CaioLins I mean $\langle \varphi, x-a \rangle := \varphi (x-a)$.

Comment: yeah, I'm just being nitpicky. The proof is right.